# Change the Dashboard Graph in version 1.7/1.12 of Magento

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento, magento-1.7

In previous versions of Magento (1.6 and before for CE, 1.11 and before for EE) the graph on the admin Dashboard would reflect the count of total orders taken. Since 1.7/1.12 this has now been changed to reflect orders that have been invoiced. We use custom statuses and like having the Dashboard graph as a quick heart beat type report on sales. However, none of our orders ever reach an invoiced status because of how we handle back end order processing (not through Magento)

How can I change the dashboard graph to report on Processing, Invoiced, and our custom status for an order? Our custom status has been tied to Processing so I may only need to query for Processing and Invoiced. According to Magento Support this kind of modification is possible but I am not sure where to start looking besides the /app/design/Adminhtml/default/default/template/dashboard/graph.phtml file. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer from Oleg Ishenko points you in the right direction, but is not quite comprehensive.
1. In the module you create, you need to override `Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Order_Collection`: so in your `config.xml` put:

```
...
    <global>
        <models>
            <yourmodule>
                <class>Namespace_Yourmodule_Model</class>
            </yourmodule>

            <reports_resource>
                <rewrite>
                    <order_collection>Namespace_Yourmodule_Model_Reports_Resource_Order_Collection</order_collection>
                </rewrite>
            </reports_resource>
        </models>
    </global>
...
```

2.Then create the class (respecting the path) and in this class you need to override 2 methods:

```
<?php
/**
 * Show all orders, not only the invoiced one
 */
class Namespace_Yourmodule_Model_Reports_Resource_Order_Collection extends Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Order_Collection
{

    protected function _prepareSummaryLive($range, $customStart, $customEnd, $isFilter = 0)
    {
        $this->setMainTable('sales/order');
        $adapter = $this->getConnection();

        /**
         * Reset all columns, because result will group only by 'created_at' field
         */
        $this->getSelect()->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS);

        $expression = sprintf('%s - %s - %s - (%s - %s - %s)',
            $adapter->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_total_invoiced', 0),
            $adapter->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_tax_invoiced', 0),
            $adapter->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_shipping_invoiced', 0),
            $adapter->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_total_refunded', 0),
            $adapter->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_tax_refunded', 0),
            $adapter->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_shipping_refunded', 0)
        );
        if ($isFilter == 0) {
            $this->getSelect()->columns(array(
                'revenue' => new Zend_Db_Expr(
                    sprintf('SUM((%s) * %s)', $expression,
                        $adapter->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_to_global_rate', 0)
                    )
                 )
            ));
        } else {
            $this->getSelect()->columns(array(
                'revenue' => new Zend_Db_Expr(sprintf('SUM(%s)', $expression))
            ));
        }

        $dateRange = $this->getDateRange($range, $customStart, $customEnd);

        $tzRangeOffsetExpression = $this->_getTZRangeOffsetExpression(
            $range, 'created_at', $dateRange['from'], $dateRange['to']
        );

        $this->getSelect()
            ->columns(array(
                'quantity' => 'COUNT(main_table.entity_id)',
                'range' => $tzRangeOffsetExpression,
            ))
            //BOF modification
//            ->where('main_table.state NOT IN (?)', array(
//                Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PENDING_PAYMENT,
//                Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_NEW)
//            )
            //EOF modification
            ->order('range', Zend_Db_Select::SQL_ASC)
            ->group($tzRangeOffsetExpression);

        $this->addFieldToFilter('created_at', $dateRange);

        return $this;
    }

    protected function _calculateTotalsLive($isFilter = 0)
    {
        $this->setMainTable('sales/order');
        $this->removeAllFieldsFromSelect();

        $adapter = $this->getConnection();

        $baseTotalInvoiced    = $adapter->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_grand_total', 0);
        $baseTotalRefunded    = $adapter->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_discount_refunded', 0);
        $baseTaxInvoiced      = $adapter->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_tax_amount', 0);
        $baseTaxRefunded      = $adapter->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_tax_refunded', 0);
        $baseShippingInvoiced = $adapter->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_shipping_amount', 0);
        $baseShippingRefunded = $adapter->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_shipping_refunded', 0);

        $revenueExp = sprintf('%s - %s - %s - (%s - %s - %s)',
            $baseTotalInvoiced,
            $baseTaxInvoiced,
            $baseShippingInvoiced,
            $baseTotalRefunded,
            $baseTaxRefunded,
            $baseShippingRefunded
        );
        $taxExp = sprintf('%s - %s', $baseTaxInvoiced, $baseTaxRefunded);
        $shippingExp = sprintf('%s - %s', $baseShippingInvoiced, $baseShippingRefunded);

        if ($isFilter == 0) {
            $rateExp = $adapter->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_to_global_rate', 0);
            $this->getSelect()->columns(
                array(
                    'revenue'  => new Zend_Db_Expr(sprintf('SUM((%s) * %s)', $revenueExp, $rateExp)),
                    'tax'      => new Zend_Db_Expr(sprintf('SUM((%s) * %s)', $taxExp, $rateExp)),
                    'shipping' => new Zend_Db_Expr(sprintf('SUM((%s) * %s)', $shippingExp, $rateExp))
                )
            );
        } else {
            $this->getSelect()->columns(
                array(
                    'revenue'  => new Zend_Db_Expr(sprintf('SUM(%s)', $revenueExp)),
                    'tax'      => new Zend_Db_Expr(sprintf('SUM(%s)', $taxExp)),
                    'shipping' => new Zend_Db_Expr(sprintf('SUM(%s)', $shippingExp))
                )
            );
        }

        $this->getSelect()->columns(array(
            'quantity' => 'COUNT(main_table.entity_id)'
        ));
        //BOF modification
//        ->where('main_table.state NOT IN (?)', array(
//            Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PENDING_PAYMENT,
//            Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_NEW)
//         );
        //EOF modification

        return $this;
    }

}
```

In this example I have comented the filtering by order's status, but you can easily uncoment it and put the order statuses you don't want to be counted in.

HTH

Comment: This is exactly what I needed and does the trick perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Is that last script supposed to be the Observer.php?

Comment: the "last script" is not in an observer, and I don't have a crystal ball so I can't tell you what you did wrong

Comment: Sorry, I was being stupid. I have done some modifications and have all of my code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15370910/magento-module-to-change-dashboard-graph. If you get a chance could you have a look? Thank you so much!

Comment: Are you sure that computing from fields *_invoiced is correct? If you want to compute reports for all orders not only for invoiced then imho these fields should be changed too. Howevere many thanks for showing the direction of where to look.

Answer (score 1):

I did some digging, and it looks like the collection is being built in `Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Order_Collection::_prepareSummaryLive()` . In Magento 1.7.0.2 the restriction is based on orders, which are not in stati `Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PENDING_PAYMENT` or `Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_NEW`.

Anyway, the collection filters can be manipulated here
(also [see the class file on github](https://github.com/varinen/solvingmagento_1.7.0/blob/master/app/code/core/Mage/Reports/Model/Resource/Order/Collection.php#L134)):

```
$this->getSelect()
            ->columns(array(
                'quantity' => 'COUNT(main_table.entity_id)',
                'range' => $tzRangeOffsetExpression,
            ))
            ->where('main_table.state NOT IN (?)', array(
                Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PENDING_PAYMENT,
                Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_NEW)
            )
            ->order('range', Zend_Db_Select::SQL_ASC)
            ->group($tzRangeOffsetExpression);
```

Any proposed manipulations, of course, are class rewrites :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found one proposed solution but am not having much success applying it. If someone else could verify this is a possible solution I will modify this answer reflecting so. I will also change the answer to properly apply the change without modifying a core file.

---

Open /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Orders/Grid.php and add

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('state', Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING);
```

AFTER

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/order_collection')
            ->addItemCountExpr()
            ->joinCustomerName('customer')
            ->orderByCreatedAt();
```

Comment: I did this as well, but I think this only applies to the "Last 5 orders" grid, rather than the graph.