# How to display pending orders in Magento dashboard graph

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento-1.7

Since the upgrade from 1.4 to 1.7, my magento apps don't display the pending orders quantities and values in the graph like they used to.

After some searching around, I figured it only displays "processing" (orders that have been invoiced) or "complete" orders since 1.6. I realize this makes sense for most cases, but unfortunately my company doesn't process orders through magento - they're sent by email and processed on a local ERP that is in no way connected to the magento platform.

The marketing department has been bugging me that they found this graph useful and they would like it back the way it was. I can't seem to figure out what changed in the core code though.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Our conclusion was that this file answers question.

```
<?php

class Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Order_Collection extends Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Collection
{
    /**
     * Is live
     *
     * @var boolean
     */
    protected $_isLive   = false;

    /**
     * Check range for live mode
     *
     * @param unknown_type $range
     * @return Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Order_Collection
     */
    public function checkIsLive($range)
    {
        $this->_isLive = (bool)!Mage::getStoreConfig('sales/dashboard/use_aggregated_data');
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve is live flag for rep
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isLive()
    {
        return $this->_isLive;
    }

    public function prepareSummary($range, $customStart, $customEnd, $isFilter = 0)
    {
        $this->checkIsLive($range);
        if ($this->_isLive) {
            $this->_prepareSummaryLive($range, $customStart, $customEnd, $isFilter);
        } else {
            $this->_prepareSummaryAggregated($range, $customStart, $customEnd, $isFilter);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    protected function _prepareSummaryLive($range, $customStart, $customEnd, $isFilter = 0)
    {
        $this->setMainTable('sales/order');
        $adapter = $this->getConnection();

        /**
         * Reset all columns, because result will group only by 'created_at' field
         */
        $this->getSelect()->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS);

        $expression = sprintf('%s - %s - %s - (%s - %s - %s)',
            $adapter->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_total_invoiced', 'main_table.base_grand_total'),
            $adapter->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_tax_invoiced', 'main_table.base_tax_amount'),
            $adapter->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_shipping_invoiced', 'main_table.base_shipping_amount'),
            $adapter->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_total_refunded', 0),
            $adapter->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_tax_refunded', 0),
            $adapter->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_shipping_refunded', 0)
        );
        if ($isFilter == 0) {
            $this->getSelect()->columns(array(
                'revenue' => new Zend_Db_Expr(
                    sprintf('SUM((%s) * %s)', $expression,
                        $adapter->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_to_global_rate', 0)
                    )
                )
            ));
        } else {
            $this->getSelect()->columns(array(
                'revenue' => new Zend_Db_Expr(sprintf('SUM(%s)', $expression))
            ));
        }

        $dateRange = $this->getDateRange($range, $customStart, $customEnd);

        $tzRangeOffsetExpression = $this->_getTZRangeOffsetExpression(
            $range, 'created_at', $dateRange['from'], $dateRange['to']
        );

        $this->getSelect()
            ->columns(array(
                'quantity' => 'COUNT(main_table.entity_id)',
                'range' => $tzRangeOffsetExpression,
            ))
            ->where('main_table.state NOT IN (?)', array(
                    Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_HOLDED,
                    Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED)
            )
            ->order('range', Zend_Db_Select::SQL_ASC)
            ->group($tzRangeOffsetExpression);

        $this->addFieldToFilter('created_at', $dateRange);

        return $this;
    }

    protected function _prepareSummaryAggregated($range, $customStart, $customEnd)
    {
        $this->setMainTable('sales/order_aggregated_created');
        /**
         * Reset all columns, because result will group only by 'created_at' field
         */
        $this->getSelect()->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS);
        $rangePeriod = $this->_getRangeExpressionForAttribute($range, 'main_table.period');

        $tableName = $this->getConnection()->quoteIdentifier('main_table.period');
        $rangePeriod2 = str_replace($tableName, "MIN($tableName)", $rangePeriod);

        $this->getSelect()->columns(array(
            'revenue'  => 'SUM(main_table.total_revenue_amount)',
            'quantity' => 'SUM(main_table.orders_count)',
            'range' => $rangePeriod2,
        ))
            ->order('range')
            ->group($rangePeriod);

        $this->getSelect()->where(
            $this->_getConditionSql('main_table.period', $this->getDateRange($range, $customStart, $customEnd))
        );

        $statuses = Mage::getSingleton('sales/config')
            ->getOrderStatusesForState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED);

        if (empty($statuses)) {
            $statuses = array(0);
        }
        $this->addFieldToFilter('main_table.order_status', array('nin' => $statuses));

        return $this;
    }

    protected function _getRangeExpression($range)
    {
        switch ($range)
        {
            case '24h':
                $expression = $this->getConnection()->getConcatSql(array(
                    $this->getConnection()->getDateFormatSql('{{attribute}}', '%Y-%m-%d %H:'),
                    $this->getConnection()->quote('00')
                ));
                break;
            case '7d':
            case '1m':
                $expression = $this->getConnection()->getDateFormatSql('{{attribute}}', '%Y-%m-%d');
                break;
            case '1y':
            case '2y':
            case 'custom':
            default:
                $expression = $this->getConnection()->getDateFormatSql('{{attribute}}', '%Y-%m');
                break;
        }

        return $expression;
    }

    protected function _getRangeExpressionForAttribute($range, $attribute)
    {
        $expression = $this->_getRangeExpression($range);
        return str_replace('{{attribute}}', $this->getConnection()->quoteIdentifier($attribute), $expression);
    }

    protected function _getTZRangeOffsetExpression($range, $attribute, $from = null, $to = null)
    {
        return str_replace(
            '{{attribute}}',
            Mage::getResourceModel('sales/report_order')
                ->getStoreTZOffsetQuery($this->getMainTable(), $attribute, $from, $to),
            $this->_getRangeExpression($range)
        );
    }

    protected function _getTZRangeExpressionForAttribute($range, $attribute, $tzFrom = '+00:00', $tzTo = null)
    {
        if (null == $tzTo) {
            $tzTo = Mage::app()->getLocale()->storeDate()->toString(Zend_Date::GMT_DIFF_SEP);
        }
        $adapter = $this->getConnection();
        $expression = $this->_getRangeExpression($range);
        $attribute  = $adapter->quoteIdentifier($attribute);
        $periodExpr = $adapter->getDateAddSql($attribute, $tzTo, Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface::INTERVAL_HOUR);

        return str_replace('{{attribute}}', $periodExpr, $expression);
    }

    public function getDateRange($range, $customStart, $customEnd, $returnObjects = false)
    {
        $dateEnd   = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date();
        $dateStart = clone $dateEnd;

        // go to the end of a day
        $dateEnd->setHour(23);
        $dateEnd->setMinute(59);
        $dateEnd->setSecond(59);

        $dateStart->setHour(0);
        $dateStart->setMinute(0);
        $dateStart->setSecond(0);

        switch ($range)
        {
            case '24h':
                $dateEnd = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date();
                $dateEnd->addHour(1);
                $dateStart = clone $dateEnd;
                $dateStart->subDay(1);
                break;

            case '7d':
                // substract 6 days we need to include
                // only today and not hte last one from range
                $dateStart->subDay(6);
                break;

            case '1m':
                $dateStart->setDay(Mage::getStoreConfig('reports/dashboard/mtd_start'));
                break;

            case 'custom':
                $dateStart = $customStart ? $customStart : $dateEnd;
                $dateEnd   = $customEnd ? $customEnd : $dateEnd;
                break;

            case '1y':
            case '2y':
                $startMonthDay = explode(',', Mage::getStoreConfig('reports/dashboard/ytd_start'));
                $startMonth = isset($startMonthDay[0]) ? (int)$startMonthDay[0] : 1;
                $startDay = isset($startMonthDay[1]) ? (int)$startMonthDay[1] : 1;
                $dateStart->setMonth($startMonth);
                $dateStart->setDay($startDay);
                if ($range == '2y') {
                    $dateStart->subYear(1);
                }
                break;
        }

        $dateStart->setTimezone('Etc/UTC');
        $dateEnd->setTimezone('Etc/UTC');

        if ($returnObjects) {
            return array($dateStart, $dateEnd);
        } else {
            return array('from' => $dateStart, 'to' => $dateEnd, 'datetime' => true);
        }
    }

    public function addItemCountExpr()
    {
        $this->getSelect()->columns(array('items_count' => 'total_item_count'), 'main_table');
        return $this;
    }

    public function calculateTotals($isFilter = 0)
    {
        if ($this->isLive()) {
            $this->_calculateTotalsLive($isFilter);
        } else {
            $this->_calculateTotalsAggregated($isFilter);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    protected function _calculateTotalsLive($isFilter = 0)
    {
        $this->setMainTable('sales/order');
        $this->removeAllFieldsFromSelect();

        $adapter = $this->getConnection();

        $baseTotalInvoiced    = $adapter->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_total_invoiced', 'main_table.base_grand_total'); // This will check if there is no invoice it will calculate based on the grand totals ( so when you generate and invoice u will have no issues with the numbers also )
        $baseTotalRefunded    = $adapter->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_total_refunded', 0);
        $baseTaxInvoiced      = $adapter->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_tax_invoiced', 'main_table.base_tax_amount'); // Same here for taxes
        $baseTaxRefunded      = $adapter->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_tax_refunded', 0);
        $baseShippingInvoiced = $adapter->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_shipping_invoiced', 'main_table.base_shipping_amount'); // Same here for shipping
        $baseShippingRefunded = $adapter->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_shipping_refunded', 0);

        $revenueExp = sprintf('%s - %s - %s - (%s - %s - %s)',
            $baseTotalInvoiced,
            $baseTaxInvoiced,
            $baseShippingInvoiced,
            $baseTotalRefunded,
            $baseTaxRefunded,
            $baseShippingRefunded
        );
        $taxExp = sprintf('%s - %s', $baseTaxInvoiced, $baseTaxRefunded);
        $shippingExp = sprintf('%s - %s', $baseShippingInvoiced, $baseShippingRefunded);

        if ($isFilter == 0) {
            $rateExp = $adapter->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_to_global_rate', 0);
            $this->getSelect()->columns(
                array(
                    'revenue'  => new Zend_Db_Expr(sprintf('SUM((%s) * %s)', $revenueExp, $rateExp)),
                    'tax'      => new Zend_Db_Expr(sprintf('SUM((%s) * %s)', $taxExp, $rateExp)),
                    'shipping' => new Zend_Db_Expr(sprintf('SUM((%s) * %s)', $shippingExp, $rateExp))
                )
            );
        } else {
            $this->getSelect()->columns(
                array(
                    'revenue'  => new Zend_Db_Expr(sprintf('SUM(%s)', $revenueExp)),
                    'tax'      => new Zend_Db_Expr(sprintf('SUM(%s)', $taxExp)),
                    'shipping' => new Zend_Db_Expr(sprintf('SUM(%s)', $shippingExp))
                )
            );
        }

        $this->getSelect()->columns(array(
            'quantity' => 'COUNT(main_table.entity_id)'
        ))
            ->where('main_table.state NOT IN (?)', array(
                    Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_HOLDED,
                    Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED)
            );

        return $this;
    }

    protected function _calculateTotalsAggregated($isFilter = 0)
    {
        $this->setMainTable('sales/order_aggregated_created');
        $this->removeAllFieldsFromSelect();

        $this->getSelect()->columns(array(
            'revenue'  => 'SUM(main_table.total_revenue_amount)',
            'tax'      => 'SUM(main_table.total_tax_amount_actual)',
            'shipping' => 'SUM(main_table.total_shipping_amount_actual)',
            'quantity' => 'SUM(orders_count)',
        ));

        $statuses = Mage::getSingleton('sales/config')
            ->getOrderStatusesForState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED);

        if (empty($statuses)) {
            $statuses = array(0);
        }

        $this->getSelect()->where('main_table.order_status NOT IN(?)', $statuses);

        return $this;
    }

    public function calculateSales($isFilter = 0)
    {
        $statuses = Mage::getSingleton('sales/config')
            ->getOrderStatusesForState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED);

        if (empty($statuses)) {
            $statuses = array(0);
        }
        $adapter = $this->getConnection();

        if (Mage::getStoreConfig('sales/dashboard/use_aggregated_data')) {
            $this->setMainTable('sales/order_aggregated_created');
            $this->removeAllFieldsFromSelect();
            $averageExpr = $adapter->getCheckSql(
                'SUM(main_table.orders_count) > 0',
                'SUM(main_table.total_revenue_amount)/SUM(main_table.orders_count)',
                0);
            $this->getSelect()->columns(array(
                'lifetime' => 'SUM(main_table.total_revenue_amount)',
                'average'  => $averageExpr
            ));

            if (!$isFilter) {
                $this->addFieldToFilter('store_id',
                    array('eq' => Mage::app()->getStore(Mage_Core_Model_Store::ADMIN_CODE)->getId())
                );
            }
            $this->getSelect()->where('main_table.order_status NOT IN(?)', $statuses);
        } else {
            $this->setMainTable('sales/order');
            $this->removeAllFieldsFromSelect();

            $expr = sprintf('%s - %s - %s - (%s - %s - %s)',
                $adapter->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_total_invoiced', 'main_table.base_grand_total'),
                $adapter->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_tax_invoiced', 'main_table.base_tax_amount'),
                $adapter->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_shipping_invoiced', 'main_table.base_shipping_amount'),
                $adapter->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_total_refunded', 0),
                $adapter->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_tax_refunded', 0),
                $adapter->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_shipping_refunded', 0)
            );

            if ($isFilter == 0) {
                $expr = '(' . $expr . ') * main_table.base_to_global_rate';
            }

            $this->getSelect()
                ->columns(array(
                    'lifetime' => "SUM({$expr})",
                    'average'  => "AVG({$expr})"
                ))
                ->where('main_table.status NOT IN(?)', $statuses)
                ->where('main_table.state NOT IN(?)', array(
                        Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_HOLDED,
                        Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED)
                );
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function setDateRange($from, $to)
    {
        $this->_reset()
            ->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array('from' => $from, 'to' => $to))
            ->addFieldToFilter('state', array('neq' => Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED))
            ->getSelect()
            ->columns(array('orders' => 'COUNT(DISTINCT(main_table.entity_id))'))
            ->group('entity_id');

        $this->getSelect()->columns(array(
                'items' => 'SUM(main_table.total_qty_ordered)')
        );

        return $this;
    }

    public function setStoreIds($storeIds)
    {
        $adapter = $this->getConnection();
        $baseSubtotalInvoiced = $adapter->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_subtotal_invoiced', 0);
        $baseDiscountRefunded = $adapter->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_discount_refunded', 0);
        $baseSubtotalRefunded = $adapter->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_subtotal_refunded', 0);
        $baseDiscountInvoiced = $adapter->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_discount_invoiced', 0);
        $baseTotalInvocedCost = $adapter->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_total_invoiced_cost', 0);
        if ($storeIds) {
            $this->getSelect()->columns(array(
                'subtotal'  => 'SUM(main_table.base_subtotal)',
                'tax'       => 'SUM(main_table.base_tax_amount)',
                'shipping'  => 'SUM(main_table.base_shipping_amount)',
                'discount'  => 'SUM(main_table.base_discount_amount)',
                'total'     => 'SUM(main_table.base_grand_total)',
                'invoiced'  => 'SUM(main_table.base_total_paid)',
                'refunded'  => 'SUM(main_table.base_total_refunded)',
                'profit'    => "SUM($baseSubtotalInvoiced) "
                . "+ SUM({$baseDiscountRefunded}) - SUM({$baseSubtotalRefunded}) "
                . "- SUM({$baseDiscountInvoiced}) - SUM({$baseTotalInvocedCost})"
            ));
        } else {
            $this->getSelect()->columns(array(
                'subtotal'  => 'SUM(main_table.base_subtotal * main_table.base_to_global_rate)',
                'tax'       => 'SUM(main_table.base_tax_amount * main_table.base_to_global_rate)',
                'shipping'  => 'SUM(main_table.base_shipping_amount * main_table.base_to_global_rate)',
                'discount'  => 'SUM(main_table.base_discount_amount * main_table.base_to_global_rate)',
                'total'     => 'SUM(main_table.base_grand_total * main_table.base_to_global_rate)',
                'invoiced'  => 'SUM(main_table.base_total_paid * main_table.base_to_global_rate)',
                'refunded'  => 'SUM(main_table.base_total_refunded * main_table.base_to_global_rate)',
                'profit'    => "SUM({$baseSubtotalInvoiced} *  main_table.base_to_global_rate) "
                . "+ SUM({$baseDiscountRefunded} * main_table.base_to_global_rate) "
                . "- SUM({$baseSubtotalRefunded} * main_table.base_to_global_rate) "
                . "- SUM({$baseDiscountInvoiced} * main_table.base_to_global_rate) "
                . "- SUM({$baseTotalInvocedCost} * main_table.base_to_global_rate)"
            ));
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add group By customer attribute
     *
     * @return Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Order_Collection
     */
    public function groupByCustomer()
    {
        $this->getSelect()
            ->where('main_table.customer_id IS NOT NULL')
            ->group('main_table.customer_id');

        /*
         * Allow Analytic functions usage
         */
        $this->_useAnalyticFunction = true;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Join Customer Name (concat)
     *
     * @param string $alias
     * @return Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Order_Collection
     */
    public function joinCustomerName($alias = 'name')
    {
        $fields      = array('main_table.customer_firstname', 'main_table.customer_lastname');
        $fieldConcat = $this->getConnection()->getConcatSql($fields, ' ');
        $this->getSelect()->columns(array($alias => $fieldConcat));
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add Order count field to select
     *
     * @return Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Order_Collection
     */
    public function addOrdersCount()
    {
        $this->addFieldToFilter('state', array('neq' => Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED));
        $this->getSelect()
            ->columns(array('orders_count' => 'COUNT(main_table.entity_id)'));

        return $this;
    }

    public function addRevenueToSelect($convertCurrency = false)
    {
        if ($convertCurrency) {
            $this->getSelect()->columns(array(
                'revenue' => '(main_table.base_grand_total * main_table.base_to_global_rate)'
            ));
        } else {
            $this->getSelect()->columns(array(
                'revenue' => 'base_grand_total'
            ));
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function addSumAvgTotals($storeId = 0)
    {
        $adapter = $this->getConnection();
        $baseSubtotalRefunded = $adapter->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_subtotal_refunded', 0);
        $baseSubtotalCanceled = $adapter->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_subtotal_canceled', 0);
        $baseDiscountCanceled = $adapter->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_discount_canceled', 0);

        /**
         * calculate average and total amount
         */
        $expr = ($storeId == 0)
            ? "(main_table.base_subtotal -
            {$baseSubtotalRefunded} - {$baseSubtotalCanceled} - ABS(main_table.base_discount_amount) -
            {$baseDiscountCanceled}) * main_table.base_to_global_rate"
            : "main_table.base_subtotal - {$baseSubtotalCanceled} - {$baseSubtotalRefunded} -
            ABS(main_table.base_discount_amount) - {$baseDiscountCanceled}";

        $this->getSelect()
            ->columns(array('orders_avg_amount' => "AVG({$expr})"))
            ->columns(array('orders_sum_amount' => "SUM({$expr})"));

        return $this;
    }

    public function orderByTotalAmount($dir = self::SORT_ORDER_DESC)
    {
        $this->getSelect()->order('orders_sum_amount ' . $dir);
        return $this;
    }

    public function orderByOrdersCount($dir = self::SORT_ORDER_DESC)
    {
        $this->getSelect()->order('orders_count ' . $dir);
        return $this;
    }

    public function orderByCustomerRegistration($dir = self::SORT_ORDER_DESC)
    {
        $this->setOrder('customer_id', $dir);
        return $this;
    }

    public function orderByCreatedAt($dir = self::SORT_ORDER_DESC)
    {
        $this->setOrder('created_at', $dir);
        return $this;
    }

    public function getSelectCountSql()
    {
        $countSelect = clone $this->getSelect();
        $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);
        $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_COUNT);
        $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_OFFSET);
        $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS);
        $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::GROUP);
        $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::HAVING);
        $countSelect->columns("COUNT(DISTINCT main_table.entity_id)");

        return $countSelect;
    }

    protected function _initInitialFieldsToSelect()
    {
        // No fields should be initialized
        return $this;
    }

    public function addCreateAtPeriodFilter($period)
    {
        list($from, $to) = $this->getDateRange($period, 0, 0, true);

        $this->checkIsLive($period);

        if ($this->isLive()) {
            $fieldToFilter = 'created_at';
        } else {
            $fieldToFilter = 'period';
        }

        $this->addFieldToFilter($fieldToFilter, array(
            'from'  => $from->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT),
            'to'    => $to->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT)
        ));

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Other things that may be helpful to find answers for similar problems.

1) Check if "Use Aggregate Data (beta)" is set to "No" in Configuration > Sales > Sales tab. This solution only works for "live" data (meaning, it uses the sales/order table rather than the sales/order_aggregated_created). If not, set it to "No".

2) Edit app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/dashboard/graph.phtml 
and change getChartUrl(false) to getChartUrl(true)

3) Be sure that your Class is actually used and not a local version

check_class_path.php

```
<?php 
require_once ('app/Mage.php'); 
Mage::app("default"); 
$reflector = new ReflectionClass('Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Order_Collection'); 
$t = $reflector->getFileName(); 
echo $t;
```

4) Find any potential Classes conflits in magento
  https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun

5) Clear caches like apc cache / magento cache

6) If your Magento installation was upgraded compare db schemas between fresh magento installation and yours

Comment: I have tried this before. It doesn't seem to be working. I changed from PENDING_PAYMENT to CANCELLED and NEW to HOLDED in both locations on that file, deleted cache, refreshed lifetime statistics, and nothing happens on the dashboard.

Comment: @pedropeixoto take a look into this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15675781/706466 and part
$baseTotalInvoiced    = $adapter->getIfNullSql('main_table.base_total_invoiced', 'main_table.base_grand_total');  etc...

Comment: @pedropeixoto yes you need to also change main_table.base_total_invoiced to main_table.base_grand_total ( as you want also included orders which hasn't been invoiced maybe)

Comment: I changed to core file to reflect that. But it's still not working after deleting cache and refreshing stats. You can find my core file as it is here: http://pastebin.com/Tzhz5Vqs

Comment: @pedropeixoto Maybe you are running a copy of that class in app/code/local/Mage/Reports/Model/Resource/Order/Collection.php or other extension rewrite that class. +  maybe you are running apc cache in this case you need to clear it in php with apc_clear_cache().

Comment: can you create a new file in the root directory and check if that class is using that file.
<?php
require_once ('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app("default");
$reflector = new ReflectionClass('Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Order_Collection');
$t =  $reflector->getFileName();
var_dump($t);

Comment: I am indeed using APC. I cleared opcode Cache now and repeated the process. No luck. And the dump you provided points to the app/code/core/ file too. I'm floored...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41862/discussion-between-pedropeixoto-and-arius2038)

Comment: Found a solution finally! It wasn't a DB problem after all, it was as simple as changing "Use Aggregate Data (beta)" to "No" in Configuration > Sales > Sales tab. The code works only if you don't use Aggregate Data.

Comment: I just added that confirmation to your answer in case anyone has the same setting. Thanks again!

Comment: @PawelDubiel in magento2 available ? i have same issue facing in magento2